# How do I keep a parameter passed into a block

Tags: ios, ios7, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

I'm using the iOS motion manager and it works by using a block Handler.  I have an "Acceleration" object with ...

```
@property (atomic, readonly) CMAccelerometerData * rawAccelerometerData;
```

In the .m file, I have...

```
-(void) startServices{
    [_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:_queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
        _rawAccelerometerData = accelerometerData;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){
           [delegate accelerometerUpdate:accelerometer];
        });
    }];
}
```

The Delegate is a view controller:

```
-(void) accelerometerUpdate:(Accelerometer *) accelerometer {
   _accelX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", accelerometer.rawAccelerometerData.acceleration.x];
  _accelY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", accelerometer.rawAccelerometerData.acceleration.y];
  _accelZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", accelerometer.rawAccelerometerData.acceleration.z];
```

}

But when I access `_rawAccelerometerData`, I get a `Bad Access Exception`.

My guess is that the `accelerometerData` object is getting destroyed. How do I keep it?

Comment: how are you synchronising the multiple threads in your app?

Comment: Oh, so this is a multi-threading issue?  I'm using GCD to display this information on the mainQueue.  If I add a block that contains the object that has _rawAccelerometerData as a parameter, and this parameter gets changed, does that matter?

When does _rawAccelerometerData get accessed? When the block is created, or when it is executed?

Comment: What class is this in? What is retaining the instance of that class?

Comment: How is `rawAccelerometerData` defined and how are you accessing it when you get the exception?

Comment: You said this code was in an accelerometer class. But the code uses one like it's an instance. Why don't you pass the data you just received to the method?

Comment: Are you compiling with ARC?

Comment: You are setting the instance variable `_rawAccelerometerData` on `self` (which may or may not back a property `rawAccelerometerData` on `self`). Then you access the property `rawAccelerometerData` on `accelerometer`. I fail to see how these are related.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-threading issue.  (Thanks holex for pointing me in that direction.)

_rawAccelerometerData is always being updated, and the new object is replacing the old object (which gets destroyed because of ARC).

On another thread, I am accessing _rawAccelerometerData. Occasionally, when I access _rawAccelerometerData, I am accessing an older 'copy' of the object. Since that object has already been destroyed, I get a Bad Access.